# Can not display a site collection after creating it

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, site-collection, iis

i have created a new site collection of type team site inside SharePoint 2013. it took around 50 minutes till it creates the site collection and i got the folloiwng page:-

> Central Administration : Application Management : Top-Level Site
>   Successfully Created

But when i try to access the site collection which have the following URL `https://servername:80/sites/Intranet` i receive the following error :-
"Page Can not be displayed". I checked the IIS manager under application pool and the `SharePoint - 80` was started successfully.

Can anyone advice please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you navigate to the settings page? 
`https://servername:80/sites/Intranet/_layouts/15/settings.aspx`

If yes, then your site is successfully created but the landing page is missing/corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

after creating the site collection in specific web application you should share the site for specific users, without sharing the site the users can't access..